Criteria query join with embbeded id Java JPA Hibernate
I have 2 entities (Entity A and Entity B) that I'd like to join, but later discovered it's impossible because Entity A doesn't have an object attribute (entity B) to perform left join, and Entity B has the id attribute of entity A (in the embedded id) to make the join, I could still make the join on native query entity A, but not from criteria query, can you guys help me about this?
Here's the query I'd like to join that I couldn't do on my criteria query:
SELECT * FROM ENTITY_A LEFT JOIN ENTITY_B ON ENTITY_A.id = ENTITY_.ENTITY_A_id
My entity A and B will be like this:
Entity A:
public class EntityA extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements 
Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "prod-generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "prod-generator",
        strategy = "com.thangdt.entityevent.utils.generator.MyGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 254)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 254, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private Long tenantId;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "config")
    private EventConfigDTO config;
    

}

Entity B:
public class EntityB {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EntityBId id;

    @Column(name = "ordinal")
    private Integer order;
}

public class EntityBId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "entity_A_id")
    private Long entityAId;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private Long tenantId;
}

I tried to perform the left join from entity A to entity B, but still can't do it later because entity A doesn't have Entity B attribute on it.

You may need to reconsider how you are modelling your entities. It would be super helpful if you could edit your question to include both the entity and embedded ID classes.

thanks for your feedback, i added my entity details, i hope you can help me
